# What 'using' directive do I need for WebSockets

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, compiler-errors, websocket

I'm somewhat new to C# and very new to Websockets.  I need to modify an existing application that uses sockets to use WebSockets, but the compiler gives the infamous

> ... are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

So, obviously I am missing something, but what?

Also, is there a way to force a browser to use a particular version of WebSockets?

Thanks much everyone!

Comment: WebSockets are a _client-side_ technology.

Comment: SLaks -- yes?  I am trying to modify a client.  (And it must be supported on both ends, so your comment means what?)  Italics noted, but not helpful.

Comment: It's Javascript, not C#.  The .Net framework does not have a WebSocket implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to download and install a websocket server implementation. I'm currently using the prototype from HTML5Labs found [here](http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com/prototypes/websockets/websockets/info). Note that this is a hybi spec version 9 and will only work with browsers that support the new hybi technology (EG, Chrome for sure, and I think FF7 might as well). It will not work with FF <= 6 or Safari and, of course, IE has no native websockets support as of yet. As far as I know, there is no way to specify a different version of websockets to use for your browser.

Comment: By the way, after you install the WebSockets implementation, you add an assembly reference to Microsoft.ServiceModel.WebSockets.dll to your project from the `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SDKs\WCF WebSockets\11.05.11\bin` directory and after that, the using directive to add would be `using Microsoft.ServiceModel.WebSockets;`. Check http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com/media/47685/readme.htm for the readme.

Comment: This is the direct link to download the installer http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com/media/51612/wcfwebsockets.msi (from HTML5Labs). Also, thanks for pointing out that once installed the dlls can be found at `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SDKs\WCF WebSockets\11.05.11\bin`